# Settings in PhpStorm IDE

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

I wonder what these "warnings" bellow are and how I can get rid of them.
If I hover over white markings or the arrows these will show up. But the ones coming from the arrows shows code that I already have deleted.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a warning but only a helper from the VCS component of PhpStorm.

It just marks places where something has been deleted since the last commit. If you commit the changes, the marker will disappear.

It's similar to the green and blue markings that show which lines have been added or changed since the last commit.